# Super + w & shortcut application access

Tags: shortcut-keys

Super + W is great. But after all windows get displayed, I have to either click on one with my mouse or use the arrow keys. It would be better if each window turned into a letter, so I could access it quickly. 
Anyone know if this is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible if you are a programmer and can patch the Unity Compiz plugin to achieve it. Otherwise, there is no existing solution that can provide that feature.

**Apparently though**, the <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> *Spread Mode* in Ubuntu 12.04 will support selecting displayed Windows by number (eg '1' for the left-most window, '2' for the next window to the right, etc).